# ConstraintLayout content shape changed if scrolled

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I used *constarintLayout*  as a container for my `recycleView`, And i fill my items by depend on json (Retrieved data).

So i makes some tricks here, If my retrieved **json** contain a specific value i have to make some items in my constraint layout to disappear and resize others.

All work fine, But when i scroll down and scroll up, The changed value back to old statue i don't need.

for ex: 
this marked row have different customize shape 
[image]

when scroll down and scroll up again the row lost the modified shape :
[image]

Here is my constraintLayout.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/article_subtitle"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp"
android:id="@+id/containerDetailsItem">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/technicalName"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:layout_width="141dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_main"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnailLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/technicalProfile"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/account_circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="الملف الشخصي"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/background"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/technicalAge"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/technicalExperince"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:layout_width="137dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnailLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/technicalExperince" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/technicalAge"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:layout_width="139dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/technicalExperince"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnailLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/technicalName"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnailLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-36dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/unselected"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here example for changed in layout items :

```
 if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("2")) {
            holder.ageView.setTypeface(font);
            holder.ageView.setText("\uf0ce" + " office"  );
            holder.experinceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.nameView.setTextSize(23);

            //holder.constraintView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.office_color));
        }
        if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("1")) {
            holder.ageView.setTypeface(font);
            holder.ageView.setText( "\uf19c" + " company"  );
            holder.experinceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.nameView.setTextSize(23);
            //holder.constraintView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.company_color));
        }
```

So i **edit** this data only if retrieved data called `type` equal to a specific value.

And if `type` not equal to specific `type` i let it appear in a normal shape.

My adapter :

```
    private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {


        public Adapter(Cursor cursor) {
            mCursor = cursor;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            return mCursor.getLong(ArticleLoader.Query._ID);
        }


        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_profiles_vertical, parent, false);
            final ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            ItemsContract.Items.buildItemUri(getItemId(vh.getAdapterPosition()))));
                    try {

                        int i = Integer.parseInt((String) mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.SERVER_ID));
                        Log.i(TAG, "bindViews: " + i);
                        i = i + 1;
                        Config.BASE_URL = new URL("http:/json/users?user=" + mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.SERVER_ID));
                        startService(new Intent(DisplaysActivity.this, CurrentService.class));
                        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateDisplay: "  + mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.SERVER_ID));
                        Log.i(TAG, "onClick: "  + Config.BASE_URL);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.ageView.setTypeface(typeface);
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            holder.nameView.setText(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.NAME));
            if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("2")) {
                holder.profileIcon.setTypeface(font);
                holder.ageView.setTypeface(font);
                holder.ageView.setText("  مكتب" );
                holder.ageView.setTextSize(17);
                holder.profileIcon.setText("\uf0f7");
                holder.experinceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.nameView.setTextSize(23);
                //holder.constraintView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.office_color));
            }
            if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("1")) {
                holder.profileIcon.setTypeface(font);
                holder.ageView.setTypeface(font);
                holder.ageView.setText(" شركة");
                holder.ageView.setTextSize(17);
                holder.profileIcon.setText("\uf0f7");
                holder.experinceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.nameView.setTextSize(23);
                //holder.constraintView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.company_color));
            }
            if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("3")){
                holder.profileIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ageView.setTypeface(typeface);
            }

            if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("3") && mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.STATUE).equals("1")){
                holder.ageView.setText(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.AGE) + " سنة" + " / " + "متاح ");
            }else if(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("3") && mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.STATUE).equals("0")){
                holder.ageView.setText(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.AGE) + " سنة" + " / " + "غير متاح ");
            }else if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("3")){
                holder.ageView.setText(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.AGE) + " سنة");
            }

//            holder.dateView.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
//                    mCursor.getLong(ArticleLoader.Query.PUBLISHED_DATE),
//                    System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS,
//                    DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL).toString() + "قبل");
            holder.experinceView.setText(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.EXPERINCE) + " سنوات خبرة" + " / " + mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.CITY));
            if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.THUMB_URL).length() > 5) {
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.THUMB_URL)).into(holder.thumbnailView);
            } else {
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http:logo.png").into(holder.thumbnailView);
            }


            holder.nameView.setTypeface(typeface);

            holder.experinceView.setTypeface(typeface);
            holder.technicalProfile.setTypeface(typeface);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (mCursor.getCount() < 1){
                Toast.makeText(DisplaysActivity.this, "لا يوجد محتوى", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
    }
```

This worked fine but my problem with scroll, if i scroll down and scroll up again the changed item effect gone,
 is this a bug or what ?

Comment: Thanks, so far I can't tell what went wrong because onBindViewHolder() is somehow incomplete. If ýou can post enough code to reproduce the error then I'd like to look into the problem. I have an idea or two but I'd prefer to run some tests before answering

Comment: @0X0nosugar my `onBindViewHolder()` contain lot of hold items ex:
`holder.ageView.setText("\uf0ce" + " office"  );`
so i just put a comment with the idea, it's all similar.

Comment: I think I get your point :) Well, the following constraint for the TextView with id=technicalExperince seems to be self-referencing: app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/technicalExperince" Is this a typo in this post or is it like this in your code?

Comment: @0X0nosugar it's my code, but did you think this issue can effect the view after i scroll down and scroll up again ?

Comment: No, but I don't really have that much experience with ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Next question: is the "experinceView" really GONE in this special case you highlighted? At least that's what your code example is showing

Comment: Yup.. but i highlighted the normal case for my recycle, so the normal case after scroll bacame coustmized case.

Comment: if you handling conditional visibility of text view you must handle if else both
for example
if(true)
 text.setVisibility(View.GONE)
else 
text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: Where does the code that starts with `if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("2")) {` appear? Also, do you implement `getItemViewType()` in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`? I think you are having an issue with `RecyclerView` recycling and it's not a bug. It would be helpful to see the code for the entire adapter.

Comment: @Cheticamp issue happend if scrolled down and scrolled up again... do you think it's reflect with recycleview? Should recycleview contain same shape?

Comment: I am guessing that you are not distinguishing your views enough for `RecyclerView` to recycle appropriately. A fuller look at all of your adapter, at lease the `RecyclerView` callbacks setting your first block of code in context, will be helpful.

Comment: @Cheticamp updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is with your views that you are making `gone`. Views are recycled so, let's say that view #12 is set so that an image is set to `gone`. Let's also say that #12 is recycled to display a different row from your database and that row requires the image to be visible or not `gone`. The image in view #12, since it was recycled, is still `gone` unless you explicitly make it `visible`. In other words, all information in a recycled view remains unchanged until you change it. That goes for data and any view attributes. It is easy to remember to change the data but not the view attributes.

I suggest that you add code to explicitly make a view visible if it needs to be visible.

Try your `onBindViewHolder()` with the following initial two lines to see if it helps:

```
holder.experinceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.profileIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: That's it very simple... my mistake that i don't recognize or recover old statue after scroll...

Answer (score 0):

As per i faced issue with adapter that if you handling conditional visibility of view in adapter you have to consider all conditions check below

```
 if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("2")) {
                holder.profileIcon.setTypeface(font);
                holder.ageView.setTypeface(font);
                holder.ageView.setText("  مكتب" );
                holder.ageView.setTextSize(17);
                holder.profileIcon.setText("\uf0f7");
                holder.experinceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.nameView.setTextSize(23);
                //holder.constraintView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.office_color));
            }
           else if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("1")) {
                holder.profileIcon.setTypeface(font);
                holder.ageView.setTypeface(font);
                holder.ageView.setText(" شركة");
                holder.ageView.setTextSize(17);
                holder.profileIcon.setText("\uf0f7");
                holder.experinceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.nameView.setTextSize(23);
                //holder.constraintView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.company_color));
            }
           else if (mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TYPE).equals("3")){
                holder.profileIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ageView.setTypeface(typeface);
                ///here you have to consider other views used in the conditions above to default behaviour you want
            }
            else{
            ///here you have to handle default behaviour
    }
```

after setting view gone/invisible to particular condition you need to handle visibility to view for that else it will cause problem in scroll or data change